# JQuery add fade instead of using plugin animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this news ticker plugin to display the content in a list. Unfortunately the animation uses some sort of typing animation when I need it to just fade-in and out.

How would I change the animation used in the Fiddle example to a fade-in/out animation?

Hope someone can help.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/bleachie/AvFMZ/5/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) plugin to achieve fade in/out animation

demo: http://bxslider.com/examples/multiple-slideshows

Comment: Thanks. Quite a big plugin for what I want to do. I'll have to remove some of the unnecessary functions.

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420200/simple-jquery-fade-ticker