# Simple JQuery Fade ticker stop after one minute

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've come across this accepted solution and it is about Simple JQuery Fade ticker:
[Simple JQuery Fade ticker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420200/simple-jquery-fade-ticker)

How to create using the same code that will stop after a minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aniSpd01 = 1000;
var fadeSpd01 = 1000;

$(function() {
    var startIndex = 0;
    var endIndex = $('#aniHolder div').length;
    $('#aniHolder div:first').fadeIn(fadeSpd01);

    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#aniHolder div:eq(' + startIndex + ')').delay(fadeSpd01).fadeOut(fadeSpd01);
        startIndex++;
        $('#aniHolder div:eq(' + startIndex + ')').fadeIn(fadeSpd01);

        if (endIndex == startIndex) startIndex = 0;
    }, aniSpd01);
    //NEW
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }, 1000 * 60);
});
```

Comment: I just tested it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VY9y4/1/ did you miss the `var interval =`